# Error: Extra parameter in request i used Swift 4. Why i have to pass parameters of type [String: Any]?

Tags: swift, closures, alamofire, objective-c-blocks, swift4

```
Alamofire.request(APPURL.GetAccounts, method: .post, 
                      parameters: transactionData,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                      headers: nil).responseJSON { responseData in }
```

My question is what is the reason that restricts me to only pass Dictionary of type [String:Any]?

Complete Code:

```
class func getAccounts( transactionData: [String:Any]?, withCompletionHandler: @escaping (_ response:AnyObject?)->(Void) ) {

    Alamofire.request(APPURL.GetAccounts, method: .post, 
                      parameters: transactionData,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                      headers: nil).responseJSON { responseData in

        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["Accounts"].arrayObject {
                let resultData = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                withCompletionHandler(resultData as AnyObject)
            }else{
                withCompletionHandler(nil)
            }
        }else{
            withCompletionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are describing a "limitation" of alamofire and not swift 4 itself. Plus, this is not a limitation. When you talk about parameters in alamofire is always intended a structure key value because it is impossible to handle in a generic way custom requests. If you have a custom post body, you can still do it by adding setting the postBody var of the request that is returned by alamofire. Please update your title. This is not a swift 4 related question. you want help using alamofire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON format the key has always to be string and the value can be of any type. This is how JSON works in Swift.

Comment: Was not aware of this one thanks! I was used to pass String there.